# Javascript variable replacement(CK Editor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How to replace `{$name}`, `{$city}`, `{$country}`  with dynamic value.  Dynamic value are json format. 
My requirement: Initially only users create layout design using CKEditor. Then the user will upload CSV file. All data in CSV will replace `{$value}`. That is the concept

```
<p>This is the <strong>default </strong>CKEditor installation.{$name} Source editing is provided by the Source Editing Area</a>&nbsp;plugin.</p><p>Follow the{$city}steps below to try it{$country}out:</p><ul><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button to display the HTML source of this tex {$website} {$email}in the source editing area.</li><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button again to return to the WYSIWYG view.</li></ul><form>First name:<br>
```

**JSON format:**

```
[
        {
            "name": "Lijo",
            "city": "Banglaore",
            "country": "India",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Thoams",
            "city": "Chennai",
            "country": "India",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Maria",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "country": "India",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Dravid",
            "city": "New York",
            "country": "US",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Sachin",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "city": "Canbera",
            "country": "AUS",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Would that JSON for multiple users, create multiple lines of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As op said they are getting the template from a database. I would assume it is a string.
You could use this to create a template literal.

```js
const template = "<p>This is the <strong>default </strong>CKEditor installation.${name} Source editing is provided by the Source Editing Area</a>&nbsp;plugin.</p><p>Follow the${city}steps below to try it${country}out:</p><ul><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button to display the HTML source of this tex ${website} ${email}in the source editing area.</li><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button again to return to the WYSIWYG view.</li></ul><form>First name:<br>"


const replacements  = [{
    "name": "Lijo",
    "city": "Banglaore",
    "country": "India",
    "website": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Thoams",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "country": "India",
    "website": "",
    "email": ""
  }
]

const inset = new Function('name', 'city', 'country', 'website', 'email', 'return `' + template + '`')

const filledIn = replacements .map(({ name, city, country, website, email }) => inset(name, city, country, website, email) )

console.log(filledIn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'foo', city: 'cityFoo', country: 'countryFoo'},
  {name: 'bar', city: 'cityBar', country: 'countryBar'}
]

console.log(arr.map(
  ({name, city, country}) => 
    `<p>This is the <strong>default </strong>CKEditor installation.${name} Source editing is provided by the Source Editing Area</a>&nbsp;plugin.</p><p>Follow the${city}steps below to try it${country}...`
))
```

Comment: How would this work with a template stored in the database? `eval`?